App Freezes when Swiping Left on Menu Component
When I swipe left, the view freezes but the menu component still works when swiping. Also, when it's frozen, if I just click anywhere in the frozen area, it toggles the menu, and then when I close the menu it's unfrozen and works again. What might be the problem?
 .frame(width: getRect().width)
                .overlay(
                    
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(
                            Color.primary
                                .opacity(Double((offset / sideBarWidth / 5)))
                        )
                        .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .vertical)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                menuIsShowing.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                )
            }
            .frame(width: getRect().width + sideBarWidth)
            .offset(x: -sideBarWidth / 2)
            .offset(x: offset > 0 ? offset : 0)
            .gesture(
            
                DragGesture()
                    .updating($gestureOffset, body: { value, out, _ in
                        out = value.translation.width
                    })
                    .onEnded(onEnd(value:))
            )
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showChat, destination: {
                if let user = selectedUser {
                    ChatView(user: user)
                }
            })
            .onChange(of: selectedUser, perform: { newValue in
                showChat = newValue != nil
            })
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: offset == 0)
            .onChange(of: menuIsShowing) { newValue in
                if menuIsShowing && offset == 0 {
                    offset = sideBarWidth
                    lastStoredOffset = offset
                }
                
                if !menuIsShowing && offset == sideBarWidth {
                    offset = 0
                    lastStoredOffset = 0
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: gestureOffset) { newValue in
                onChange()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onChange() {
        let sideBarWidth = getRect().width - 90
        
        offset = (gestureOffset != 0) ? (gestureOffset + lastStoredOffset < sideBarWidth ? gestureOffset  + lastStoredOffset: offset) : offset
    }
    
    func onEnd(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        let sideBarWidth = getRect().width - 90

        let translation = value.translation.width
        
        withAnimation {
            if translation > 0 {
                
                if translation > (sideBarWidth / 2) {
                    offset = sideBarWidth
                    menuIsShowing = true
                }
                else {
                    
                    if offset == sideBarWidth {
                        return
                    }
                    
                    offset = 0
                    menuIsShowing = false
                }
            }
            else {
                
                if -translation > (sideBarWidth / 2) {
                    offset = 0
                    menuIsShowing = false
                }
                else {
                    
                    if offset == 0 || !menuIsShowing {
                        return
                    }
                    
                    offset = sideBarWidth
                    menuIsShowing = true
                }
            }
        }
        
        lastStoredOffset = offset

I tried the code below, but it stops the wanted swipe drag gesture.
if value.translation.width > 0 
   out = value.translation.width
}

